# Convert HTML code to .NET string

Tags: .net, string

I have the following HTML code:

```
<P>Notes:&nbsp;&nbsp; Mails: <BR> &nbsp; 1. <A href="mailto:example@mail.com">example@mail.com</A></P>
```

and of course when I try to pass it to string it gives me error:

```
 string s =  "<P>Notes:&nbsp;&nbsp; Mails: <BR> &nbsp; 1. <A href="mailto:example@mail.com">example@mail.com</A></P>";
```

Is there a way I could just take that HTML and convert it to a .NET equivalent, preferably without changing the format?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just have to escape the quotes:

```
 string s =  "<P>Notes:&nbsp;&nbsp; Mails: <BR> &nbsp; 1. <A href=\"mailto:example@mail.com\">example@mail.com</A></P>";
```

In C# `"` denotes the beginning or end of a string, to use a `"` inside a string you need to 'escape' it like this `\"`. You may also use [verbatim string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) of the format

```
string s = @"this is a string with "" <-- a quote inside";
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape the quotes:

```
string s =  "<P>Notes:&nbsp;&nbsp; Mails: <BR> &nbsp; 1. <A href=\"mailto:example@mail.com\">example@mail.com</A></P>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string s = "<P>Notes:&nbsp;&nbsp; Mails: <BR> &nbsp; 1. <A href='mailto:example@mail.com'>example@mail.com</A></P>";
```

You can not use the double quotes inside the string without escaping them. Or use the version I posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s =  "<P>Notes:&nbsp;&nbsp; Mails: <BR> &nbsp; 1. <A href=\"mailto:example@mail.com\">example@mail.com</A></P>";
```

You have to escape the quotes with a slash "\".

Answer (score 0):

There's no string literal in C# where you don't have to escape double quotes.

```
var str1 = "<A href=\"mailto:example@mail.com\">";
var str2 = @"<A href=""mailto:example@mail.com"">";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "<P>Notes:&nbsp;&nbsp;Mails:<br />&nbsp;1.<A href=\"mailto:example@mail.com\">example@mail.com</A></P>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

For compile time support, you can escape quotes with `\"`, as demonstrated so many times by others (so I'll not repeat), you can use a literal string `@"..."` where you can escape quotes with `""`, or you can paste your string in a resource file and let Visual Studio handle the escaping for you.

Alternately, you can often get by if you replace the double quote for a single; however, this can sometimes be a problem if your string contains JavaScript, as having two types of quotes at hand may be a necessary evil.

At run time you can avoid escaping by reading the text from a file, database, or some other resource; however, I get the impression this is not your intent.